# Given the convergence of a sequence, determine the convergence of the series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have a sequence that converges to$$\{ a_{n} \} = \frac{1}{2}$$

I need to determine if the series converge or diverge $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, (a_{n})^{n}}{n} $$

I am a bit confused here, when I go from $n$ to $n+1$, how does $a_{n}$ change?

Comment: You have not defined the sequence properly. Do you mean  $a_n=\frac 1 2$ for all $n$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n = -\ln(1+x)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy My bad, it's actually the sequence converges to $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|a_n| <\frac  3 4$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Now $|\frac {(-1)^{n} a_n^{n}} {n}|\leq (\frac 3  4)^{n}$ and $\sum (\frac 3  4)^{n}<\infty$. This shows that the series is absolutely convergent (hence also convergent). Note that the first few terms of a series can be neglected for determining convergence.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n$ is a constant sequence. It doesn't "change".

About the series, it converges. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

The sum can be computed, if you need it.